# Keep aspect ratio of div using css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a `div` and keeping its aspect ratio to 16 : 9 using css. I made a google search, and quickly found this: [How to maintain the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css#10441480). So I tried doing it myself, but came upon a problem. When I add text inside, the ratio changes, and isn't 16 : 9 ratio anymore.

#### JSFiddle

When you remove all the `li's`, then the ratio is correct. How can I keep the aspect ratio even when adding text inside?

Code Snippet:

```css
div {
    width: 70%;
}
ul {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Links to Jsfiddle should be accompanied by the relevant code (check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user2314737 Ok. Lemme do that right now.

Comment: I don't understand how this is even a question, you're staring right at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Build a div that has the wanted aspect ratio, with the padding-technique described in the link you gave.
2. Make that div positioned relative, absolute or fixed, and add a child element into it. Make this child positioned absolute, with `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` set to 0. The child will always have the same aspect ratio the outer div has, no matter what its content is.
3. If you need it, set `overflow:hidden` on the inner element.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul class="inner">
        <li>List items go here</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; // 9/16
    position: relative; // or absolute or fixed, but not static
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden; // or scroll, auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `ul` absolutely positioned within your green `div` so it will not affect your padding. Here's the CSS you need:

```
div {
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```